# iOS Dispatch get the last item of the delay time

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I am using dispatch_after in my textfield

(in func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) )

to only fire my println once every 5 secs.

Use case:
- Type "abcde" fastly
- Get back "abcde" println back

Instead of (after 5 secs)
- a
- ab
- abc
- abcd
- abcde

```
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        println("test: \(searchText)")
    }
```

Comment: You have used textDidChange method which gets call on every change in text field. You should write your code in textfielddidengediting method.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a new `var timer: NSTimer?`

Then in your textDidChange function you could do something like

```
if timer == nil {
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "printTextFieldInput:", userInfo: textField, repeats: false)
}
```

The corresponding function to print would look like:

```
func printTextFieldInput(timer: NSTimer) -> Void {
  if let textField = timer.userInfo as? UITextField {
    println(textField.text)
  }
  timer.invalidate()
  self.timer = nil
}
```